# Select or boolean aggregate function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to ask you how in PostgreSQL can you check if one of boolean values in table's column is true using select or aggregate function?

Answer (score 35):

There are few boolean specific [aggregate functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) you may use: `bool_and`, `bool_or`, `every`.

In your particular case you need `bool_or` aggregate.
The query is as simple as this:

```
SELECT bool_or(my_column) FROM my_table
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer! Explained shortly and accurately

Answer (score 6):

You can't use SUM(DATA) but you could cast the value (see below) to int (0=false, 1=true). However it may be more efficient to use EXISTS(...), specially if you are not interested in the number of TRUE values.

```
create table test(data boolean);
insert into test values(true), (false);
select sum(cast(data as int)) from test;
select exists(select * from test where data);
```

Comment: Be precisely: select exists(select * from test where data='true');
It works! Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

To know whether there is at least 1 true value:

```
select sum(cast(data as int)) > 0
```

This is better than the exists solution because it can be embedded into a larger query, maybe containing group by and other where clauses